# What does skipping a draw phase mean for an opponent in Gloom?

Tags: gloom

In Gloom, you can play modifiers on opponents' characters, and the action applies to that character's player.  For example, one card might say "discard your hand".  It has good stats, but the discard is a balancing downside.  You can use that against an opponent to make them discard their hand.

But, what does "Skip your draw step this turn" mean for an opponent?  Do they skip their (nonexistent) draw step during your turn, or does it apply the next time it can (their turn?).  Along with that, does a "Discard your hand. Skip your draw step this turn" mean an opponent would essentially miss two turns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1232101/rules-clarification-gloom-2nd-edition-was-shunned) from one of the game's designers:

> Correct: most likely you will start your next turn with no cards and
>   be unable to do anything, effectively missing a turn.
>
> In first edition, the effect was simply "Skip your next turn." By the
>   current rules, you can still end up being able to play if some other
>   card effect ends up giving you cards - for example, someone cheers up
>   your shunned character. Also, if you are playing with Stories (from
>   Unquiet Dead), you could use an action on your turn to claim a story.
>
> A key point here is that you skip your draw phase "THIS" turn - the
>   turn on which the card is played. If you use the card on yourself, you
>   don't get to draw back up at the end of the turn. If someone else
>   plays it on you on THEIR turn, you wouldn't draw back up anyway, so
>   this effect does nothing. You don't skip your NEXT draw phase.